# How to make a regular expression in postgres lazy

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have this sql expression:

```
regexp_matches(view_definition,'(ms_sub_[0-9]+)(.*group by)','ig')
```

which is trying to return the text between 'ms_sub_' and 'group by'. It returns all the text to the last occurrence of 'group by' but I only want the text to the next occurrence of group by. I've tried to make 'group by' lazy but can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the first greedy quantifier, then you may use a lazy `*?` quantifier with the dot:

```
regexp_matches(view_definition,'ms_sub_[0-9].*?group by','ig')
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/HEIE99480)

When you used `[0-9]+`, you set the whole expression greediness to "greedy", and the `.*?` you used later was treated as a *greedy*, `.*`, pattern. You might also use `\d+?` to get the same results. The only difference is what your capturing groups may contain, but in this case, you seem to only want whole match values.

If you care about the captured values, you may use

```
(ms_sub_\d+?(?!\d))(.*?group by)
```

where `(?!\d)` lookahead will make sure you `\d+?` matches all consecutive digits there are after `ms_sub_` while still using a lazy quantifier.

If you expect at least 1 non-digit char after the `ms_sub_<digits>` between it and `group by`, you may use `(ms_sub_\d+?)(\D.*?group by)` where `\D` matches any char other than digit.

Comment: Thanks, i hadn't realised a greedy trumps a following lazy. The reason i have the [0-9]+ is because the number of digits following 'ms_sub_' varies (between 1&3) and i want to return the 'ms_sub_123' separate from the text that follows. Do you know if that possible?

Comment: @paul I have already suggested `(ms_sub_\d+?(?!\d))(.*?group by)` (PostgreSQL regex supports lookaheads). If you have more lax requirements, try also `(ms_sub_\d+?)(\D.*?group by)` (here, the 2nd group is required to start with at least 1 non-digit char, so it cannot be just `group by`).

Comment: Apologies, I didn't correctly read your response - i missed the lookahead.

Comment: @paul I could have provided a more specific workaround/alternative solution if you explained the exact requirements for the pattern. I only dwelt on the lazy/greedy issue since the question is more about that.

Comment: For those who want to downvote when seeing `.*?`: the point is not that `.*?` must be used, but that the first `+` quantifier sets the whole greediness level in the regex. And that is not obvious. Just [using `*?` won't work](http://rextester.com/MYM45556).